# Facebook API, Graph, FQL,... and email search

Tags: facebook, api, email

I am working on a project related to both school and work where I would like to combine data from a college entrance application (which includes email address) and Facebook data, even a minimum amount of data, such as number of "friends" or any other public info they've put out there.  Am I correct that you can't really programmatically search Facebook by email address?  Feel free to make any suggestions.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can search Facebook by email address, you just can't *reliably* search Facebook by email address.

For instance, you can make this query with a user access token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=user&q=USER@EMAIL.NET&access_token=TOKEN
```

I've tried this with a few people I know who are on Facebook, where I know their email address, but I am not friends with them. (Mostly my wife's friends).

In my testing, only about 20% of these queries return a Facebook user_id. I'm not sure if they don't have the email I know linked to their user account or if they have their privacy set to restrict their email address.

Once you have their user_id, you can access all their public information at

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID
```

You don't need an access token to get this information.

Comment: Nice and thanks for your response.  I think if I can get a search to work, what you mentioned is a potential issue I would run against is those who use one email address for applying to a college and a different one to sign into Facebook, which can't really be avoided.  When I tried your link for getting public information, it worked obviously but I was hoping it would reveal a little more - for example, if I go to a stranger's page, I can often see the number friends this person has, but this doesn't show that.

Comment: Yes, Facebook reveals more to someone within the Facebook ecosystem than they will to an anonymous API call. As for emails, I have close to a dozen right now based on different roles I have. Facebook knows two of those. I think that is a major failing with your plan.

Comment: Indeed - a student may use DistinguishedStudent@hotmail.com for their college application and PartyRockinLadyLover7@yahoo.com for their Facebook application.  I have been exploring Twitter as well and it seems that it's email search is limited to manual searches and even that, we run into the same issue.

Comment: You could try something like the [Dandy ID API](http://www.dandyid.org/api/documentation) and see if it gives you any better insight into who is the person behind your email address. Good luck.